# cannot change the default port on nginx

Tags: nginx, webserver, gitlab

I am using the nginx web server bundled with gitlab and I have SSL setup and I am using the non-default port i.e. I have the URL setup as

```
external_url 'https://www.myserver.com:2443'
```

However, when I connect with this address, I get a `connection was reset` error. Running, `gitlab-cal tail` shows

```
 bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

I am not sure why it still is looking at port 80. Is there some other setting that I must set here.

Comment: Have you executed `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` after you changed the config?

Comment: yeah, I did but that did not help.

Comment: It seems it was my `nginx['redirect_http_to_https] = true` option. I needed to change the port as well but that caused another different issue